# Does priority_queue of priority_queues exist?

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue

I am trying things with **priority_queues** and got stuck in following case.

```
(1, 4) (2, 4) (3, 4)
(9, 4) (8, 4) (7, 4)
(4, 4) (6, 4) (5, 4)
```

I want to store this kind of data: So I tried `priority_queue<priority_queue<pair<int, int>>> A` and this line compiled fine (without error). So I am assuming it should be a valid type.

**Why I need this?**

I want to access these integers in decreasing order as `9,9,9,9, 8,8,8,8, 7,7,...`
So each integer should be accessible the the number of times it is mentioned **(integer, number of times)**.

Now I am not sure how do I enter values in this structure.

What I am trying and getting error at is this

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        priority_queue<pair<int, int >> temp;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            temp.push(make_pair(i, 0));
        }
        A.push(temp);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `and getting error` please post the error message. I guess the inner priority_queue should be sorted using the first `int` from the pair. But how is the outer priority_queue sorted? `this kind of data` I do not understand what "this kind of data" it represents and how. It it's a priority_queue, it's sorted, why is `9` before `7`?

Comment: `priority_queue<priority_queue<pair<int, int>>>` doesn't compile with GCC. It does compile with clang; I'm not sure why. It requires that instances of `priority_queue<pair<int, int>>` be comparable, but `priority_queue` doesn't have `operator<` defined for it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes I am compiling with clang. Interesting to know that GCC doesn't. Thanks for the input

Comment: Given that you seem to initialize the data once, might I suggest to just use a `vector<tuple<int,int,size_t,size_t>>` and sort it with a custom compare function but in reverse, so you can just `pop_back` all the entries?

Answer (score 1):

The elements in a [`std::priotity_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) need to be compared to determine their order. By default the elements are compared by `std::less` but you can provide your own comparison as long as it provides a *strict weak ordering*.

Unfortunately a `std::priority_queue` does not provide any comparison operator. Since you can't compare two priority queues for ordering I don't think they can be nested the way you want.

Comment: Is there a better way to store such data? I can use the inner priority queue. but how can I order the _n_ number of priority_queues based on the total of the queue.

Comment: @RC0993 To be honest, I'm a little fuzzy on the middle part of your question. I'm not sure how the pair elements are related and how they're being used.

Comment: @RC0993 Do you **need** a nested priority_queue? You can use a single priority_queue, set, or sorted vector to store pairs and then access them in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass custom comparators to priority queues that would let you compare elements and sort them.

```
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

struct less_pair_first : public std::less<less_pair_first> {
    constexpr bool operator ()(
                const std::pair<int, int>& a, 
                const std::pair<int, int>& b
            ) const {
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
};

using inner_priority_queue = std::priority_queue<
    std::pair<int, int>, 
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>,
    less_pair_first
>;

struct less_inner_priority_queue : public std::less<inner_priority_queue> {
    bool operator ()(
                const inner_priority_queue& a,
                const inner_priority_queue& b
            ) const {
        // I think `inner_priority_queue::value_compare` could be used here in std++17
        return less_pair_first()(a.top(), b.top());
    }
};

using my_priority_queue = std::priority_queue<
    inner_priority_queue,
    std::vector<inner_priority_queue>,
    less_inner_priority_queue
>;

int main() {
    my_priority_queue A;

    unsigned rows = 3, cols = 4;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        decltype(A)::value_type temp;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            temp.push(std::make_pair(i, 0));
        }
        A.push(std::move(temp));
    }

    for (decltype(A)::value_type i; i = A.top(), !A.empty(); A.pop()) {
        for (decltype(i)::value_type j; j = i.top(), !i.empty(); i.pop()) {
            std::cout << j.first << " " << j.second << "|";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Tested in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fjMaFf).